# How to know which satellite took the image?

Tags: remote-sensing, imagery, satellite

I am having trouble finding which satellite took the images I have.
Most are from digital globe.

I read through the metadata and the .imd file. 
I found date and time but not the name of the satellite. Where can I find this information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to https://www.digitalglobe.com/sites/default/files/ISD_External.pdf you should have a field called `satellite` with a  mnemonic like:

```
“QB02”, “WV01”, “WV02”, “WV03”, “GE01”, “Aerial”
```

Which I assume correspond to the satellites operated by DigitalGlobe:

```
QuickBird, WorldView 1/2/3, GeoEye-1, IKONOS
```